# Automatically dismiss View Controller in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I have 3 `ViewControllers` labeled "A","B" and "C". Right now, "A" is the `rootViewController` of the window and it presents "B" modally. When a button is tapped in "B" it is supposed to present C modally immediately and dismiss "B" automatically. How can I do that? I saw all the examples in StackOverflow but they are not working

```
@IBAction func proceedBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    weak var pvc = self.presentingViewController
    let vc = ThirdViewController()

    pvc?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: { [weak self] in
        self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

This is my code. Any help?

Comment: "it's not working" is not very helpful. Please share what you tried with protocols and delegates and explain what part is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the help, finally I have done this using delegates and protocols. We need to create the protocol in SecondViewController and we have to use that protocol in FirstViewController.

```
// Declare protocol and variable delegate in SecondViewController
protocol dismissVC {
func presentVC()
}
var delegateVC: dismissVC? = nil

// Call that protocol in FirstViewController
  class FirstViewController: UIViewController, dismissVC {

        func presentVC() {
        let pickVc = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: 
        nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "third-VC") 
        as! ThirdViewController
        pickVc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        present(pickVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

  }

  // Action method in SecondViewController
@IBAction func proceedBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        self.delegateVC!.presentVC()
    }

// and at last call that delegate when you try to use segue 

   let SecondVc = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second-VC") as! SecondViewController
                Vc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
                Vc.delegateVC = self // add delegate here
             self.present(Vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
 // At last call delegate
    yourVc.delegateVC = self
```

Answer (score 3):

First dismiss your **b** view controller and then present **c** view controller on **A**.

try this.

```
let vc = ThirdViewController()
let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

if let parent = self.presentingViewController{
    self.dismiss(animated: true){
         parent.present(navVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I use this code it shows the red screen but i want to present my UI i have created how can i do that ?

Comment: It shows the whole black screen I think it's because of navigation. Is there any way to connect it through navigation?

Comment: If you want ThirdViewController present with navigation controller then create a new navigation controller and set ThirdViewController as root view controller of it and present new navigation controller instead of vc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166691/discussion-between-v-rohit-and-tailor).

Answer (score 3):

if you use `segue` then use '`Unwind segue`'

for this write given code in your 'A view controller'

```
@IBAction func unwindToThisViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegueForC_VeiwController", sender: nil) 

}
```

In B_viewcontroller, On press button call 'Unwind segue'. Then firest B_VC dismiss and then C_VC present on A_VC.

Note:- only one View_controler present on any View_controler. If you want to add another first remove or dismiss another Viewcontroller from that View controller.

Comment: Thanks for help but I found the answer : ))

Comment: And you must learn how to use 'Unwind segue' its help you so many ways. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using **delegation** pattern EX:UIImagePickerViewControll

```
class A:UIViewController, BDelegate {

  @IBAction func onOpenBController(_ sender:Any) {
      let bVC = B()
      bVC.delegate = self
      present(bVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func bControllerDidSelect(_ controller: B) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) //Dismiss B controller
    present(C(), animated: true, completion: nil) //Present C controller
  }
}

class B:UIViewController {
    weak var delegate:BDelegate?

    @IBAction func onSomeClickEvent(_ sender:Any) {
       delegate?.bControllerDidSelect(self)
    }
}

protocol BDelegate: class {
    func bControllerDidSelect(_ controller:B)
}

class C:UIViewController {

}
```