# How to dismiss previous Viewcontroller after presenting new Viewcontroller using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

My Scenario, In my project I am maintaining three `ViewController` `(Main, VC1 and VC2)`. In main `ViewController` I am maintaining `UIButton`, This button click to `VC1` presenting model view controller.  Again, `VC1` I am maintain `UIButton` with action click to present model to `VC2`. After `VC2` presenting I need to dismiss VC1.

```
//  presenting ViewController
var presentingViewController: UIViewController! = self.presentingViewController

self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) {
      // go back to MainMenuView as the eyes of the user
      presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: What kind of segue do you use to present VC1? What you try to achieve might break navigation expectations.

Comment: @idmean from the main viewcontroller button action I am doing present model by using coding with         let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller: PreViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "previewcontroller")  as! PreViewController
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
        self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @jackios how are you presenting VC2 from VC1 ??

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49234141/automatically-dismiss-view-controller-in-swift-4

Comment: Are you open to pushing the controller instead of presenting it?

Comment: @PGDev - I am doing present view controller

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to dismiss VC1 after VC2 is presented (I assume that VC1 is the presenter or VC2 ??) Cuz to me, VC2 is on top of VC1 visually, so user has no idea VC1 is dismissed or not. So What is goal/function do you want to realize here? E.g. If you need to go back to the main viewController, you can use unwind segue if UI is done in IB, or a coordinator referring to all VCs if everything is done programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in `VC2`'s close button action

```
var vc = self.navigationController?.presentingViewController
while vc?.presentingViewController != nil {
    vc = vc?.presentingViewController
}
vc?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Hi @RajeshKumar....Thank you I will try and let you know. Btw where can I put this line?

Comment: Bro where can I place this line@RajeshKumar

Comment: @jackios do you have any button to comeback to Main from VC2?

Comment: Yes @RajeshKumarR I am maintaining closing button in VC2. if I place your code nothing working bro

Comment: @jackios Try self.navigationController?.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Its working first time bro. Second time I am calling directly VC2 from main...now if I try to close above line not working.

Comment: Can you please help to solve it. Very first time your code working second time I am presenting VC2 from main vc. Now, you code not working. @RajeshKumar

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work:

You need to have a UIViewController as a base, in this case `MainViewController` is the base ViewController. You need to use a protocol to call the navigation between Controllers.

you can do using protocol:-

In to your  FirstViewController setting Protocol :

```
protocol FirstViewControllerProtocol {
    func dismissViewController()
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate:FirstViewControllerProtocol!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    @IBAction func goBack(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { 
            self.delegate!.dismissViewController()
        }
    }
```

Now in your MainViewController

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, FirstViewControllerProtocol {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func goToFirstViewController(sender: AnyObject) {
    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(String(FirstViewController)) as! FirstViewController
    viewController.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



//MARK: Protocol for dismiss
func dismissViewController() {
    if let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(String(SecondViewController)){
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I can't get you. VC1 and VC2 both I am maintaining present model. Both VC root is Main ViewController. @Bhavisha Kharti

Comment: This won't work create a protocol in VC2 and call it in your VC1 on button click it will dismiss the VC2 but the delegate will call in Main VC so it will show the VC 3

Comment: @wings main viewcontroller to present VC1 and from VC1 to Present VC2 with navigation bar and present model (bottom to top transition) I am using. Here, VC1 to VC2 presenting time VC1 can't able to dismiss. If I close VC2 then again I can see VC1. How to solve this?

Comment: Edited my answer. please check

Comment: @BhavishaKhatri. I think you didn't understand my question. After presenting VC2 I need to dismiss VC1. Also, I am maintaining main viewcontroller. Main to Present model VC1 and VC1 to present model VC2. If I close VC2 I can see VC1 because after VC2 present I need to dismiss VC1.

Comment: @jackios After dismissing VC2, don't you want to see VC1?

Comment: Yes. After VC2 close I need to see only mainviewcontroller @RajeshKumarR

Comment: @jackios Did you try my updated answer? Isn't working?

Comment: @jackios and how are you presengin VC2 from VC1? Show that code

Comment: let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) let controller: PreViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "previewcontroller") as! PreViewController let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller) self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil) @RajeshKumarR

Comment: Yes @RajeshKumarR I am maintaining closing button. if I place your code nothing working bro.

Comment: (correct me if I am wrong) IMHO Bhavisha Khatri's code provides you a general pattern that you can use delegate method to call back to your presenting viewController after you dismiss a viewController. There are several ways you can easily navigate back/forth to a specific viewController, but it depends what your real problem is.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem statement, what you can do is present `VC2` using `Main` instead of `VC1`.

We can get the reference to `Main` in `VC1` using

```
self.presentingViewController
```

When `VC2` is presented, dismiss `VC1` in the `completionHandler` of `present(_:animated:completion:)` method

```
class Main: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func onTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC1")
        self.present(vc1, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class VC1: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func onTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2")
        vc2.view.backgroundColor = .blue
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        self.presentingViewController?.present(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class VC2: UIViewController {

}
```

This approach is giving the expected output. Let me in case anything else is required.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open vc2 from the mainVC - In order to do this you need a delegate method which will tell mainVC to close the current opened vc (i.e. vc1) and in the success block open vc2.

Code Snipet:-

dismiss(animated: false) {
   //Open vc2
   present(vc2)
}

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to call dismiss from the view controller over which your other view controllers are presented(Main in your case).

As you stated your situation in the question above Main presents VC1 and VC1 then presents VC2:
then calling Main.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) will dismiss VC1 and VC2 simultaneously.

If you don't have a reference to the root controller(Main), you could chain a couple of presentingViewController properties to access it; Something like this in the topmost controller(VC2):

```
presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [present(_:animated:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present) method which takes a completion. Inside that you can `dismiss` your VC1.

Your code will look something like this

```
@IBAction func ButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    present(VC2, animated: true) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try it before add here?

Comment: I think it should be like this 

self.dismiss(animated: false) {
            self.present(vc, animated: true)
        }